# Postgresql Trigger When ALL columns listed are updated

Tags: postgresql, triggers

From the postgresql [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createtrigger.html) :

> For UPDATE triggers, it is possible to specify a list of columns using
>   this    syntax:
>
> UPDATE OF column_name1 [, column_name2 ... ]
>
> The trigger will only fire if at least one of the listed columns is mentioned as a target of the update.

Is there a way to make the trigger fire only if ALL of the listed columns are targeted in an update?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make the trigger fire only if ALL of the listed columns are targeted in an update?

No. The trigger will fire if *any* of the listed columns are updated.

But, in principle, you can compare the values of OLD.column_name and NEW.column_name, and execute code only when all the columns have changed.

You should be aware, though, that it's perfectly legal to update a column with the value it already has.  For example, start with this table.

```
foo_id  foo_desc
1       First
2       Second
```

```
update foo
set foo_id = 1, foo_desc = 'First'
where foo_id = 1;
```

All the columns were targeted; none of them changed to different values. (They *did* change, but they changed from 1 to 1 and from 'First' to 'First'.)

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I don't care if the new values differ from the old values, just that the columns listed were targeted... The trigger I have updates a "last updated" date and I only want to update the date if all of the listed columns were targeted. So I don't care what the values are/were just that each listed column was updated. I'm thinking it isn't possible. Oh well - the "any of the columns" trigger will work for now.